Why does my code work for every valid test case but II and XVIII?
Here is my code:
#include <studio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { 
    char possibilities[21][5] = {
        "", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", 
        "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI", "XII", 
        "XIII", "XIV", "XV", "XVI", "XVII", 
        "XVIII", "XIX", "XX"
    }; 

    char input1[6]; 
    char input2[6]; 
    int total = 0; 
    char output[10] = "";

    printf("the first Roman numeral: ");
    scanf("%s", input1);

    printf("Enter the second Roman numeral: ");
    scanf("%s", input2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        if (strcmp(input1, possibilities[i]) == 0) {
            total += i;
        }
        if (strcmp(input2, possibilities[i]) == 0) {
            total += i;
        }
    }

    while (total > 0) {
        if (total >= 10) {
            total -= 10;
            strcat(output, "X");
        } else {
            strcat(output, possibilities[total]);
            total = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Result = %s", output);
    return 0;
}

I have tested III and XVII, IV and XVI, essentially everything "around" II and XVIII, and gotten a correct output. I have no idea where the problem is.

Input? Expected output? Actual output?

This seems like the perfect opportunity to learn how to debug your programs. For example by using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Also build with extra warnings enabled, and treat them as errors.

@Someprogrammerdude In this specific case there won't be a warning for the problem. It's legal in C

XVIII needs 6 chars (5+1 for NULL): char possibilities[21][6]

Nitpick: XX + XX will produce XXXX with your code rather than the more conventional XL.  The conventions were fairly flexible so XXXX is not definitively wrong, but you'd need to cope with such notations in a more general program.  Your current design is ill-equipped to handle numbers into the hundreds, let alone the thousands.

Your string array is too "short".
char possibilities[21][5]

can only hold strings with max 4 characters as a C style string needs a zero termination character in the end. However, "XVIII" has 5 characters so there is no room for the termination. So possibilities[18] is not a valid C-style string.
Use
char possibilities[21][6]
                       ^

to make room for the termination.
DEBUG TIP:
So how did I find the bug? I used a very famous debugger which actually comes with C. No need to install anything - it's already there. Its name is printf
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    printf("Compare with %s\n", possibilities[i]); // DEBUGGER
    if (strcmp(input1, possibilities[i]) == 0){
        printf("Match on input1 - add %d\n", i); // DEBUGGER
        total += i;
    }
    if (strcmp(input2, possibilities[i]) == 0){
        printf("Match on input1 - add %d\n", i); // DEBUGGER
        total += i;
    }
}

The debugger showed:
Compare with I
Compare with II
Match on input1 - add 2
Compare with III
Compare with IV
Compare with V
Compare with VI
Compare with VII
Compare with VIII
Compare with IX
Compare with X
Compare with XI
Compare with XII
Compare with XIII
Compare with XIV
Compare with XV
Compare with XVI
Compare with XVII
Compare with XVIIIXIX
Compare with XIX
Compare with XX

where it's easy to see that the problem is near "XVIIIXIX" as this is not the correct compare-string.
BTW:
Never do
scanf("%s", input1);

as it allow users to overflow your input buffers.
Actually, never use scanf. Just forget all about it. Use fgets for  user input.

Not saying you're wrong about scanf vs. fgets but it might not be amiss to point out how scanf can be used to prevent that overflow issue.

@Chris No need to do that. Once OP forgets all about scanf, OP doesn't need to know.

@4386427 that's a great way to avoid mistakes but it doesn't teach OP much about secure code practices :)

@mono Oh yes it does. Use fgets. Never use scanf. That's a good advice for "secure code practices"

it is been years passing that i have urge to ask,- why is scanf so bad? what is wrong with limiting scan size in scanf argument string?

@user14063792468 Because scanf is so full of pitfalls. It takes a master to manage scanf. And master know better ways. Search SO and you'll find an extreme numbers of Q where scanf is used incorrect. A little space before %c or after... what does it mean!? Only experts know... and they don't touch it

@4386427 i started to fear scanf. i never used fgets. im cornered :) please tell me that the experts  are, at least to some degree, OK with sscanf. othervise im in a deep trouble :)

@user14063792468 sscanf is much better than scanf as you have much better control of the data to be scanned. sscanf has pitfalls too but not as bad as scanf

The code you provided currently uses a loop that subtracts values and appends characters, but it doesn’t fully cover all cases, especially when total is less than 10.
while (total > 0){
    if (total >= 10) {
        total -= 10;
        strcat(output, "X");
    } else {
        strcat(output, possibilities[total]);
        total = 0;
    }
}

try to use an array of tuples, allows directly map integers back to Roman numeral characters.
    ...
    scanf("%5s", input1); // prevents potential overflow
    ...
    scanf("%5s", input2); // prevents potential overflow
    ...
    struct {
        int value;
        const char *symbol;
    } roman_map[] = {
        {10, "X"}, {9, "IX"}, {8, "VIII"}, {7, "VII"}, {6, "VI"},
        {5, "V"}, {4, "IV"}, {3, "III"}, {2, "II"}, {1, "I"}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && total > 0; i++) {
        while (total >= roman_map[i].value) {
            strcat(output, roman_map[i].symbol);
            total -= roman_map[i].value;
        }
    }


OP's code does a table lookup for values less than 10. That part looks fine to me.
